# Apex Job Gets Stuck Processing

Tags: apex, batch, dynamic-apex

I have the following problem. There is an Apex Scheduled job that runs everyday at 2AM that gets stuck during processing.

As seen in the image below, the batch process reaches 330 and then stalls until I abort it. I have seen it stall for a week. Now that I know this is an issue, every morning I come in and abort the job.

At some point I am going to have to collapse the entire process, but before I do that I want to see if this is a quick fix.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this? Below is an image of the job as well

[image]

```
    String query2 = 'SELECT accountid AccountId, Count(id) result FROM Opportunity Where AccountId != null AND ( Recordtype.Name = \'Pre Platform Discussion\' OR Recordtype.Name = \'New Business\' OR Recordtype.Name = \'Pre Opportunity\' OR Recordtype.Name = \'Conversion\' ) AND isclosed = true GROUP BY AccountId' ;
    DynamicBatchApexAR batch2 = new DynamicBatchApexAR('AccountId', 'result',  'Closed_Sales_Opportunity__c', query2);

    Database.executeBatch(Batch2, 25);
```

Below is the Batch Class:

```
global class DynamicBatchApexAR implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult> {



        public String sObjectIdKey;
        public String sObjectResultKey;
        public String sObjectFieldToUpdate;
        public String query;
        public List<Id> ListOfIDs;
        DynamicSObjectUpdater sObjectUpdater = new DynamicSObjectUpdater();

    
    global DynamicBatchApexAR(String arIdKey, String arResultKey, String fieldToUpdate, String soqlQuery, List<Id> whereInClause ) 

    {
        

        sObjectIdKey            = arIdKey;
        sObjectResultKey        = arResultKey;
        sObjectFieldToUpdate    = fieldToUpdate;
        query                   = soqlQuery;
        ListOfIDs               = whereInClause;
    }

    // DynamicBatchApexAR('AccountId', 'result', 'Contacts__c', query1);
    
    global DynamicBatchApexAR(String arIdKey, String arResultKey, String fieldToUpdate, String soqlQuery ) 
    {
        

        sObjectIdKey            = arIdKey;
        sObjectResultKey        = arResultKey;
        sObjectFieldToUpdate    = fieldToUpdate;
        query                   = soqlQuery;
    }
    
    global Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        return ListOfIDs == null ? new BulkIterable(query) : new BulkIterable(query, ListOfIDs);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
    {

            for(sObject sObj: scope)
            {
                
                AggregateResult ar      = (AggregateResult)sObj;
                ID sObjectId            = (ID)ar.get(sObjectIdKey);
                Decimal arResult        = (Decimal)ar.get(sObjectResultKey);
                Map<String, Object> sObjectFieldsToUpdate = new Map<String, Object>{
                    sObjectFieldToUpdate => arResult
                };

                sObjectUpdater.getUpdateSObject(sObjectId, sObjectFieldsToUpdate);
            }

            sObjectUpdater.updateSObjects();


    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you scheduled a debug log for that time period?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how to use the debug logs strategically.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_logs